# PDF generation in orbeon

Tags: java, grails, pdf-generation, orbeon

I have an orbeon form and when someone has fill out the form, I want it to create a pdf and sent it to my webservice.

Right now, when the form is fill out and you press sent, the document id, app name and form name are sent to the webservice.

Can anyone help me with a guide or an example ?

The webservice is in grails (JAVA).

Best regard 
Martin

Answer (score 2):

You have to customize a process for your send/save button.
Have a look a this: 
http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/index.html

Scroll to 'Customizing processes'. You can find here an example of the process for the send button:

```
<property
  as="xs:string"
  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.acme.hr"
  value='require-valid
         then pdf
         then email
         then send("http://example.org/")
         then navigate("/success")
         recover navigate("/failure")'/>
```

The 'pdf' action should generate a pdf document.
To get an url of the document you can customize the 'send' action: go to 
'Core Form Runner actions' at http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/index.html and find 'send'. In the 'content' property you can specify 'pdf-url' to get the pdf url. The 'uri' property should point to your webservice.
Once your web service receives a pdf url, you can issue a request using the url to download document.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `pdf` action anymore and the PDF is created automatically if you have `pdf-url` specified.